# How to inherit standard report parser class in qweb reports odoo v8

Tags: report, odoo-8, qweb

I've create one custom module, using this module want to inherit standard report parser class in qweb reports.
What is the standard flow to inherit report parser class in odoo v8...???

Comment: What do you mean with report parser, could you give an example? What are you trying to do?

Comment: for example inherit the payroll payslip report we get the error: get_payslip_lines doens exist